# ngIf si un campo de mi base de datos está vacío o no

Tags: angular

Tengo un sistema de usuarios, el cual puedo editar los campos, tipo puedo cambiarle el nombre, los apellidos **y su foto de perfil**, entonces quiero hacer que si el usuario tiene una foto de perfil asignada cuando lo registré me la cargue para poder ver la imagen que tiene asignada.

Entonces quiero hacer un ngIf si el campo avatar está vacío no me muestres nada, pero si el campo avatar tiene imagen que me muestre la imagen

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: @PabloLozano no se como decirle que si el campo de la base de datos está vacío no me muestre nada

Comment: Tienes que acotar el problema: Angular no tiene acceso a una base de datos, tendrá acceso a daos que llegan desde el servidor. Tendrás que comprobar esos datos. Y si no explicas qué estás intentando o cómo son esos datos, no podemos ayudarte. `*ngIf`no es más que un `if` normal, simplemente haciendo "si ( el campo está vacío) entonces no mostrar, en otro caso mostrar" funcionará

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomando en cuenta que tu objeto de usuario es algo como esto:

```
const user = { name: 'Usuario', avatar: 'https://tusitio.com/imagen.png' };
```

En el template puedes hacer lo siguiente para ver si tu objeto viene con la propiedad avatar. Ten en cuenta ésto tomará datos "falsy" ya sea un '', 0, false o null.

```
<img *ngIf="user.avatar" [src]="user.avatar" />
```